# Linux Expect/TCL Comm Port Comunication Cisco Switch

Tags: tcl, expect, at-command, cisco

I have done much reading on TCL/Expect and wrote the following script to connect to the comm port on my RPi-Kali-Linux box.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

;#set the portID and open it for reading and writing
set portID [open /dev/ttyUSB0 r+]
set baud 9600

;#Configure the port with the baud rate
;#and dont block on read, dont buffer output
fconfigure $portID -mode "9600,n,8,1"
fconfigure $portID -blocking 0 -buffering none

;#Write to the comm port by sending a carrage return
spawn -open $portID
puts -nonewline $portID "<CR>\r"
after 1000
puts "Modem echo: [read $portID]"


close $portID
```

Everything works fine up until I try to read from the serial port.

When I connect to the switch manually using minicom, I am greeted with the standard "Welcome to minicom" banner. From there, I press enter (carrage return) and I can then interact with the switch with standard Cisco AT-Commands. But from using the above script, I see no output.

I therefore do not know what to "expect" so I cannot proceed accordingly with configuring the switch via the script.

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

---

---

---

EDIT: From comments and more reading, I have modified the above script to what we see below. Commands now transfer to the Cisco Switch, although it seems as if the serial port is still getting traffic. The terminal also freezes when I try to manually log into the switch to check the configuration. I think the Serial Port is not closed. I am unsure what I did wrong.

I was also told not to call $portID manually after using the "spawn" command. I, therefore, commented out any "puts" that would call this port. Because of this, I am unsure how to display the output results while the script is executing.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
;#exp_internal 1 ;#Can enable this line for debugging. add -df above

;#set the portID and open it for reading and writing
set portID [open /dev/ttyUSB0 r+]
set baud 9600

;#Configure the port with the baud rate
;#and dont block on read, dont buffer output
fconfigure $portID -mode "9600,n,8,1"
fconfigure $portID -blocking 0 -buffering none

spawn -open $portID
set timeout 2
send -- "\r"
after 100
;#puts "Modem Echo: $portID"

;#expect -re "Would you like to enter the initial configuration dialog?" ;#Something wrong with this line, it is not matching
;#using the below instead
expect -re "yes/no"
after 100
send -- "no\r"
after 100

send -- "enable\r"
after 100
;#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "configure terminal\r"
;#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

;#At a later date, modify this next line to take user input on the number
;#of ports on the switch in question
send -- "interface range GigabitEthernet 0/1-8\r"
;#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "power inline static\r"
;#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 2000

send -- "no cdp enable\r"
;#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "exit\r"
;#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "exit\r"
;#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "copy running-config startup-config\r"
after 100
;#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"

after 100
;#expect -re "Destination filename" ;#Problem with this line
;#going to ignore what to expect and just send a return
send -- "\r"
expect "#"
after 100
send -- "exit\r"
expect "#"

;#close $portID
close
```

Comment: You can start with the `autoexpect` command -- that will launch an interactive shell session, and you'll manually do what you need to do: autoexpect will record that session and save it as an expect script that you can review and edit.

Comment: While developing, turn on expect's verbose debug output so you can see what is being seen and what patterns do and do not match: use `#!/usr/bin/expect -df` or add `exp_internal 1` under the shebang.

Comment: Thank you for the debugging tip, it is now turned on. For the usage of "autoexpect", I am unsure how to use expect commands in a BASH shell. I was unable to do so using "chsh -s /usr/bin/expect"

Comment: Looking closer, I see that autoexpect really won't help you here. It's much more useful when you have to ssh to a remote machine and interact with some programs there. Why are you trying to change your login shell to expect? That's hardcore.

Comment: I realised I can use standard BASH commands, I was just testing autoexpect earlier. (I didnt know if I needed to use the "spawn" command. I ended up logging into the switch using "screen /dev/ttyUSB0")

Comment: Btw, when I used autoexpect, it did not log any commands when I was connected to the switch in question. I still have no idea how to send a carrage return using expect,  so I can enter the switch> prompt and continue entering commands.

Comment: In expect, you "hit enter" with `send "\r"`

Comment: Funny, I tried that before and I didn't <i>seem</i> to work. With debugging enabled, more reading documentation, and the output of each line with the statement " puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]" " I am able to see the results of the "send" command. Very exciting!! Thank you kindly for your help. I will edit my port to reflect the full code once done and document it as a walk-through.

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix Expect's operations on a channel with Tcl's; once you hand control over with `spawn -open`, you need to use `send` instead of `puts` to write to the channel, and `expect` instead of `read` to read from the channel.

```
set portID [open /dev/ttyUSB0 r+]
fconfigure $portID -mode "9600,n,8,1"
spawn -open $portID
# From here on, DO NOT USE $portID YOURSELF!

send "\r"
# You may need to think what you're trying to receive here
set timeout 2
expect {
    -re {(.*)\n} {
        puts "Received line: $expect_out(1,string)"
        exp_continue;   # <<< KEEP ON WAITING
    }
    timeout {
        # Do nothing on timeout
    }
}

close
```

Comment: thank you for the above. I am still digesting it and reading more on https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect I will post an edit to the original post now; I was able to get a working script, but it seems as if the Serial Port won't close and I have to disconnect the USB Cable physically so I can reconnect to the switch manually, to verify the execution of the script.