# Linux Expect/TCL Serial Port Not Closing

Tags: linux, bash, serial-port, tcl, expect

I wrote a simple TCL/Expect script to automate some commands to a Cisco Switch. The script sends the single line commands, though I have ran into two problems.

One, the shell now shows me expect1.1> and not root>
This is now permanent on my Kali Linux RPi box. I thought the default shell changed, so I tried "chsh /usr/bin/bash" with no luck. I then entered "#!/usr/bin/bash" as well as "#!/usr/bin/env bash"

The terminal still shows expect1.1> and every time I use a new command like "ls", "cd" or another environment command I get an incremental value such as "expect1.2", "expect1.3", etc.

Two, after running the commands, the serial port becomes busy. I know this because when I launch a new terminal and try to connect to the switch using Minicom, I can not connect. In order for me to connect, I have to unplug the ethernet cable from the switch, and reconnect.

Anyone know why I have the two above issues?

The script I wrote/ran is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# exp_internal 1 ;# Can enable this line for debugging. add -df above

# set the portID and open it for reading and writing
set portID [open /dev/ttyUSB0 r+]
set baud 9600

# Configure the port with the baud rate
# and dont block on read, dont buffer output
fconfigure $portID -mode "9600,n,8,1"
fconfigure $portID -blocking 0 -buffering none

spawn -open $portID
set timeout 2
send -- "\r"
after 100
# puts "Modem Echo: $portID"

# expect -re "Would you like to enter the initial configuration dialog?" ;# Something wrong with this line, it is not matching
# using the below instead
expect -re "yes/no"
after 100
send -- "no\r"
after 100

send -- "enable\r"
after 100
# puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "configure terminal\r"
#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

# At a later date, modify this next line to take user input on the number
# of ports on the switch in question
send -- "interface range GigabitEthernet 0/1-8\r"
# puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "power inline static\r"
# puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 2000

send -- "no cdp enable\r"
# puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "exit\r"
#puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "exit\r"
# puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"
after 100

send -- "copy running-config startup-config\r"
after 100
# puts "Modem Echo: [read $portID]"

after 100
# expect -re "Destination filename" ;#Problem with this line
# going to ignore what to expect and just send a return
send -- "\r"
expect "#"
after 100
send -- "exit\r"
expect "#"

# close $portID
close
```

I received much help from this community, on this post:
[Linux Expect/TCL Comm Port Comunication Cisco Switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52819052/linux-expect-tcl-comm-port-comunication-cisco-switch)

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try putting the command `exp_internal 1` early in your script to make Expect print diagnostic information.

Comment: All, issue one is resolved. I changed the shell and reboot.

Comment: @donal I have that as part of my script commented out. I didnt see output pertaining to the port not closing.